# How to pass arguments to SPServices function request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spservices, parameter

In SPServices library, I make a search request using:

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "Query",
    queryXml: queryText,
    completefunc: searchComplete
});

function searchComplete(xdata, status) {

}
```

So this means it will call `searchComplete` when the search completes. The parameters of `searchComplete` is `xdata` and `status` which the SPServices library gives you. But I want to add some my own parameters to the `searchComplete` function, how can I add them?

I don't want to create global variables or anything.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you considered something like this?

```
$().SPServices({
    operation: "Query",
    queryXml: queryText,
    completefunc: function(xdata, status){
       //code to set your variables
       searchComplete(xdata, status, yourVariables);
    }
});

function searchComplete(xdata, status, yourVariables) {

}
```

Comment: oh, I didn't think of that. That should be able to solve my problem, I'll give that a try.

Comment: Very glad I could help.